# Remove Rearranged Arrays in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy product generator (using `meshgrid`) which finds the product of two arrays (similar to `itertools.product`). The problem is that it generates arrays which contain the same elements, but rearranged (thus `numpy.unique` doesn't filter them).

For example, if I have an array like this:

```
[[0, 0]
 [1, 0]
 [0, 1]
 [1, 1]]
```

I would need a result like this:

```
[[0, 0]
 [1, 0]
 [1, 1]]
```

Since `[1, 0]` and `[0, 1]` are the same for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `numpy >= 1.13.0`, you can use `np.unique` on previously sorted array:

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]])
>>> a
[[0 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 1]]
>>> b = np.unique(np.sort(a, axis=1), axis=0)
>>> b
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 1]]
```